# Как запустить выполнение gulp?

Tags: html, css, gulp, npm

при выполнении команды gulp watch выдает такое

```
   PS D:\templates\bitlex> gulp watch
fs.js:25
'use strict';
^

ReferenceError: internalBinding is not defined
    at fs.js:25:1
    at req_ (D:\templates\bitlex\node_modules\natives\index.js:137:5)
    at Object.req [as require] (D:\templates\bitlex\node_modules\natives\index.js:54:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\templates\bitlex\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:1:37)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:827:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
PS D:\templates\bitlex>
```

файл package.json

```
{
  "name": "cdm",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "cdm project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "litesite",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.23.7",
    "del": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-cache": "^1.0.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-cssnano": "^2.1.3",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^4.1.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.1",
    "gulp-uglifyjs": "^0.6.2",
    "imagemin-pngquant": "^5.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "graceful-fs": "^4.2.3",
    "gulp-cli": "^2.2.0",
    "minimatch": "^3.0.4",
    "natives": "^1.1.6",
    "npm": "^6.12.1"
  }
}
```

файл gulpfile.js

```
var gulp        = require('gulp'),
    sass        = require('gulp-sass'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
    concat      = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify      = require('gulp-uglifyjs'),
    cssnano     = require('gulp-cssnano'),
    rename      = require('gulp-rename'),
    del         = require('del'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant'),
    cache = require('gulp-cache'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

gulp.task('sass', function(){
    return gulp.src('app/sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(autoprefixer(['last 15 versions', '> 1%', 'ie 8', 'ie 7'], {cascade: true}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', function(){
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: 'app'
        },
    });
});

gulp.task('scripts', function(){
    return gulp.src([
        'app/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'
    ])
    .pipe(concat('libs.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/js'));
});

gulp.task('css-libs', ['sass'], function(){
    return gulp.src('app/css/libs.css')
    .pipe(cssnano())
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
});

gulp.task('clean', function(){
    return del.sync('dist');
});

gulp.task('clear', function(){
    return cache.clearAll();
});

gulp.task('img', function(){
    return gulp.src('app/img/**/*')
    .pipe(cache(imagemin({
        interlaced: true,
        progressive: true,
        svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
        une: [pngquant()]
    })))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/img'));
});

gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync', 'css-libs', 'scripts'], function(){
    gulp.watch('app/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('app/*.html', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('app/js/*.js', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('build', ['clean', 'img', 'sass', 'scripts'], function(){
    var buildCss = gulp.src([
        'app/css/style.css',
        'app/css/libs.min.css',
    ])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));

    var buildFonts = gulp.src('app/fonts/**/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/fonts'));

    var buildJs = gulp.src('app/js/**/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));

    var buildHtml = gulp.src('app/*.html')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Comment: Скинь версию to Gulp 3.9.1,
"npm install gulp@^3.9.1"

Comment: скинул, в вопросе добавил код ошибки

Comment: попробуй установить node 11.15.0

Comment: теперь выдает вот такую ошибку, изменил в вопросе

Comment: помогла эта статья https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54433794/gulp-internalbinding-is-not-defined

Comment: npm install natives@1.1.6